# Not able to unload child(external) swfs that is loading from main(Navigation) movie as3

Tags: events, flash, event-dispatch-thread

I have a Navigation.swf where i am loading multiple swfs using switch case statement based on the user choice (like a website navigation) aboutus.swf and contactus.swf etc, its loading perfectly.

Now in the child SWF's i have close_btn to unload the loaded SWF itself when user clicks on it. but i am not able to make it working. i have been reading help/articles form 2-3 months and found that it can be done using Event Dispatcher but somehow the codes i tried did not works for the close_btn. or it could not communicate to my main movie.

or do i need to load child swfs as movieclip ? to make the event dispatcher work from child swf so it can trigger the unloader function in main SWF and unload the loaded swf ?

please can u show me a code that can work

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
i have found a temporary solution to this 
but its worthless when my content position differ.

i have made a close button and hidden it on main( navigation movie) and when child swf is loaded i have made the close button visible, it works fine but button comes at a FIXED location on stage so the problem is if my content's postion is not near the close button then close button looks ODD on stage...so i have to have the close button inside the child SWF and not on the Main movie...

please see http://www.indianstitchers.com/ and click on facility to see how ODD the close button looks.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to help you without code samples. However I would recommend you to use LoaderMax which will make loading and unloading external media a piece of cake:
http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/
Hope that helps!

In the mean time you may try that:

in your main swif:

```
childSwif.addEventListener("closeChild", onChildClose);
function onChildClose(event:Event):void
{
    removeChild(childSwif);
    childSwif.unloadAndStop();
    // or watever you need to do to close it
}
```

in your child swif:

```
dispatchEvent("closeChild");
```